# Install Debian netinst on macbook pro 2018

Tags: debian, dual-boot, macintosh

I'm trying to install Debian 9.5.0 netinst on a `MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)`, but can't even boot the installer. I took the following steps:

1. I made a live USB with Etcher of `debian-9.5.0-amd64-netinst.iso` following https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos
2. I changed the secure boot settings in the Startup Security Utility to No Security https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208330
3. I rebooted the laptop holding the `⌥ Option Key` at startup
4. I selected EFI boot option.

This is as far as I got as I got the message `A software update is required to use this startup disk`. This had an option to update which I did, I then reattempted step 3 and 4 and got the same message.

Does anyone know if it is even possible to install on this version of MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 3):

I hate to be the one to break it to you (and I hope I'm wrong), but to my knowledge the new T2 chip causes a lot of issues.  Looking at the DebainOn support page (this will tell you supported hardware), I don't see any versions aside from MacBook Pro 8,2 (yours would be 15,2 I would assume).

DebianOn: [link](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple)

Macbook Pro Install Guide: [link](https://wiki.debian.org/MacBookPro)

Hopefully somebody responds and has a workaround, but as far as I can tell it doesn't appear to be possible "yet".

**EDIT:**

More evidence confirming my above statement:

> Short answer - you can't run anything less than the version of macOS that came with the 2018 MBPs. You've got a new generation Intel processor, the new Intel support chip(s) for that new generation processor, and Apple's T2 chip in the 2018 MBP. macOS 10.13.3 is not going to have the required drivers to support all (or any) of those changes. - Posted: 7/26/18 at 9:04 AM by sdagley

^ The above statements were not from me and I have included the original poster's name.  The link to his post is found here: [link](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/28836/macbook-pro-2018-model-can-it-run-macos-10-13-3)

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of work that people have done to get Macbooks and Macbook Pros with the T2 security chip to work with linux. If you are still looking to get linux to work on or if anyone else is looking, have a look at https://t2linux.org/

I can speak to the functionality of Linux with the T2 chip, as I am currently using Arch Linux on a 2019 Macbook Pro to type this (including functional touch-bar). I would personally recommend using the Arch Linux internet-enabled install (mentioned/linked [here](https://wiki.t2linux.org/distributions/arch/installation/)), but there are also resources for Ubuntu, Fedora, and a number of other distros available too. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a pure debian install available.

Be warned that it may be slightly more involved compared to a normal installation, and that some features may be non-functional (for example, bluetooth and automatic headphone plug-in detection in my case).