# Linux dual boot on Macbook Pro 2020

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, dual-boot, macintosh

I have a Macbook Pro and I've been trying to get a Linux installed on it on Dual Boot.

The Wifi, keyboard, and touchpad don't work.
I was able to install Ubuntu 20 on it and then Linux Mint 20 on it, but in both cases, none of the essential hardware worked.

I tried installing the drivers and all. But I feel like support for the 2020 Macbook Pro just isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

I also wrote [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709266/533187) to roughly this question at [Install Debian netinst on macbook pro 2018](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/480377/97255), it has some more details.

Short answer, newer Macbooks/Macbook Pros use the T2 security chip which changes how the keyboard and wifi and stuff connect to the computer. If you do want to use Linux on them, you should have a look at https://t2linux.org/, they have a installation guides for a variety of different distos, including Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you mentioned, the information at https://t2linux.org/ is golden!

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue. It might not be possible. I saw this:
As of right now, you cannot install Linux on the internal SSD of a newer MacBook Pro or Mac Pro (2018 or later). You can still install on an external drive, however.

Here: https://www.lifewire.com/dual-boot-linux-and-mac-os-4125733